# Adding to Google Group based on Google Spreadsheet data validation

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-groups

So I'd like to preface this with the fact that I am **NOT** a programmer.  I know a ***little*** Python, but that's about it.

So this is what I'm trying to do:

User fills out a Google Form and the responses are dumped into a spreadsheet.  As a part of the form, their email address is captured in "'Form Responses'B:B"

Not sure if this is even possible, but I'd like to know:

```
for row X If column P = yes and column c = Accept and column F = Yes
 Capture email from Column B and add them to GoogleGroup and send Welcome_Email
```

Please help!  :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script is JavaScript.
When you build the form in Google Forms, set the Data Validation for the email field to require email address. That way you don't have to hassle with validating it yourself.
http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2013/09/four-new-ways-to-customize-your-google.html

Once the form is built, go to Tools, Script Editor, and make a new Blank Project.
Replace any code in there with this:

```
function addToGroup(e){
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var emailAddress = itemResponses[#].getResponse();
  var group = GroupsManager.getGroup("group name").addMember(emailAddress);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, "Welcome to Group Name!", "You have been successfully added to Group Name");
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)

Replace # with the zero-indexed number of the column containing the email addresses, and group name is the mailbox name of the group on your Google Apps domain.

Then you just need to send the welcome email. 
Save the project, and go to Resources> Current Script's Triggers. Set it run the addToGroup script on FormSubmit, Authorize it when prompted, and that should be it for you.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/groups-manager

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60757

This only works with Google Apps accounts, and only if you have the Provisioning API turned on in your domain admin console. If you're using a standard consumer Google account, they don't have anything available to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a few searches on this forum on words like [email](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Dsend%20email) or [groups](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Dgroup) you'll find quite a few scripts and if you spend a couple of hours looking at how they are built you'll be able to write something that does what you want...

If at that moment you meet some unexpected difficulties you'll be welcome to ask for help if you show what you've done.